# How to move the arrow by dragging and then after that to toss/throw it?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch, swipe

In my application I have one arrow image with fix center and I can rotate it by the touch move method on the same center.

But I also need to toss/throw the arrow after doing some rotation with touch move. How can I toss the arrow?

Comment: toss the arrow, i suppose it means to rotate after a while and let go? it's got to do with some physics calculation of your own

Comment: yes ,it something like i rotate the arrow for some time with touch move and than give swipe event for to rotate it randomly on fix center Do You Have Any Idea thank You For Replying  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-use-gestures-in-iphone-application/

You can refer to this for some basic events like swiping or touching.

For Physics engine, I suppose you can refer to this :
http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-physics/